# Alguien sabe como puedo hacer este tipo de consultas Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Necesito tener un constructor de consultas. La única forma que se me ha ocurrido es hacer un string, y en el string formar la consulta eloquent. Solo tengo problema en ejecutar la consulta.

```
$variable = "where('a','asd')->get()";
return Modelo::$variable;
```

Sale este error:

*Access to undeclared static property: App\Models\Api\Ela\Modelo::$variable"*

Comment: Cual es tu caso de uso? para qué necesitas ese constructor de consultas? quizás se te pueda recomendar alguna alternativa

Comment: Estoy construyendo un API que funciona muy similar a como lo aria graphQL. Siempre recibo un json con los limitadores (restricciones) y con las fields (campos que requieren). Por lo tanto debo de construir las consultas con los limitadores. en algunos casos son wheres en otros son limits, chunks, etc.

Comment: si quieres hacer algo similar a GraphQL prueba este paquete: [Laravel GraphQL](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql)

Comment: Si ya había visto el paquete gracias pero no es lo que necesito en concreto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes ir construyendo la consulta Eloquent en base a lo que te llegue de la siguiente manera:

Según lo que entendí te llegan por json diferentes parámetros para armar la consulta, suponiendo que unos de esos filtros que te llegan se llama filtro_nombre, y luego de encodear y procesar el json o como lo quieras manejar, lo que vino en ese parámetro queda guardado en un variable `$filtro_nombre` o la misma es `null`;

```
$query = Miobjeto::select("un_campo")
->when($filtro_nombre != null, function ($query) use ($filtro_nombre) {
    return $query->where('nombre', $filtro_nombre);
})
//aca puedes seguir agregando todos los when necesarios.
->get();

return $query;
```

Ahora si quieres también puedes usar Query Builder:

```
$query= DB::table('mis_objetos')->select("un_campo");

if($filtro_nombre != null)
    $query->where('nombre',$filtro_nombre);

//aca puedes seguir construyendo la consulta.

return $query->get();
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Genial justo es lo que necesito, muchas gracias por tu explicación es muy clara.